# TFS first page ( landing page) before selecting the project team

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

How can I customize the home page of team foundation? I mean the first page ( landing page) before selecting the project team.

[image]
The requirements to add some general dashboards ad queries across the projects the user is assigned on it.

Note:

- the environment is TFS 2015 On-promise.
- the project page is easy to edit and add parts on it, how can we do same on tfs home page.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

There are no cross-project dashboards. You can, however, create cross project *work item queries* and put them on dashboards. However, team projects are intended by design to be isolated from one another. A good way to think of a team project is as a portfolio of related applications.

The suggested way to enable reporting across a portfolio of applications is to store all related projects in a single team project and separate the individual applications by creating teams.

Comment: thanks Daniel Mann for reply, my first requirement is to customize and edit this page (landing page (home page, welcome page) ) of the tfs (the first page cumming when i enter to TFS before i go into a project. so what is the way to add web parts same as what is possible in project home page?

Comment: See the first sentence of my answer: *You can't.* That page cannot be modified.